# htaccess 301 Redirect only if query string is present

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to include a redirect (best would be a 301 redirect) to an external domain only if a query string is present?

```
Example:
domain.com => domain.com
domain.com?query-string => another-domain.com?query-string
```

Thank you very much!

@anubhava Thank you very much for your help. 
Now I have some additional conditions I would like to add:

```
first-domain.com => https://www.first-domain.com
www.first-domain.com => https://www.first-domain.com
http://first-domain.com => https://www.first-domain.com

first-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/first-domain/?query-string
www.first-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/first-domain/?query-string
http://first-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/first-domain/?query-string
https://www.first-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/first-domain/?query-string

second-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/second-domain/?query-string
www.second-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/second-domain/?query-string
http://second-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/second-domain/?query-string
https://www.second-domain.com?query-string => https://www.another-domain.com/second-domain/?query-string
```

Comment: Please show your attempt as well

Comment: I did not attempt it, because I'm not sure if it is possible at all. I think it might not be possible at all.

Comment: Add few more examples of source and target URLs as `?id=5` in source is becoming  `/test5` in target.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your comment. I changed my question to a more general form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess of old domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^another-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://another-domain.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

- `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .` makes sure query string exist.
- Query String will be automatically forwarded to target URL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it tonight.

Comment: Is this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$` equal to `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .`

Comment: In my local environment (local.test.de) it does not work. I will try it online within the next hour. I added some new requirements in my question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to change `RewriteRule . http://another-domain.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]` to `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://another-domain.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]` to make it work.

Comment: Actually just needed to replace `.` with `^`. As in updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! I works great. Could you explain me, what the {REQUEST_URI} does?

Comment: As name suggests `%{REQUEST_URI} ` is a variable to contain request URI.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the 3rd condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\.info$ [NC]` because I wanted to exclude the Top-Level-Domain. This works fine. When I try to add a path to the condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\.info/just-this-path$ [NC]` the rule breaks.

Comment: Please avoid changing further requirements in this question. You can ask a new question I will surely help you but changing requirements so many times is not fair.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216299/discussion-between-phantom-and-anubhava).